# Visual Studio Visual Studio MVC asp.NET Google Map

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, google-maps

How can i display markers on this map i created? `.Marker("1.2233424, 4.865876)` won't work form me?

```
@using Jmelosegui.Mvc.GoogleMap
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-12">
          @(Html.GoogleMap()
             .Name("map")
             .Height(400)
             .Width(700)
           )
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get multiple markers on the same map you will want to use the bounds method. This example uses javascript.

Html

```
<div itemprop="map" id="googleMap" style="height:400px;width:100%;"></div>


                <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
```

Javascript

```
var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(YourLat, YourLng);
var myCenter2 = new google.maps.LatLng(YourSecondLat, YourSecondLng);

function initialize() {
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(myCenter, myCenter2);
    var mapProp = {
        zoom: 12,
        scrollwheel: false,
        draggable: false,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myCenter,
        map: map,
    });
    var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myCenter2,
        map: map,
    })
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

The map.fitBounds(bounds) will just center the map between your markers so all markers will be on the screen.

Comment: great Thank-You :)

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax it's wrong. You need to use

`.Markers(m => m.Add().Title("Hello World!"))`

Check [the documentation](http://www.jmelosegui.com/map/marker/SimpleMarker) to learn more

Comment: great thank you, so say if i wanted to add multiple markers to show cities in Europe how could i achieve this?

Comment: You continue adding Markers

Comment: .Markers(m => m.Add().Title("long", "lat"))
.Markers(m => m.Add().Title("long1", "lat1"))
.Markers(m => m.Add().Title("long3", "lat3"))
so could i keep adding several markers likethis?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `.Center(c => c.Latitude(1.2233424).Longitude(4.865876))`

```
Html.GoogleMap()
            .Name("map")
            .Height(300)
            .Center(c => c.Latitude(1.2233424)
                          .Longitude(4.865876))
            .Markers(m => m.Add().Title("Hello World!"))
```

Source: [jmelosegui docs](http://www.jmelosegui.com/map/marker/SimpleMarker)

Comment: great thank you, so say if i wanted to add multiple markers to show cities in Europe how could i achieve this?